# Unable to connect the configured development Web server Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I use

Visual Studio 2013

and when I run a project, I get this error :

`Unable to connect the configured development Web server.`

Here is a solution for Visual Studio 2008 and I'm searching through these steps :
http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/250134-Unable-connect-ASP-NET-development-Server.aspx

Here ; `Tools->External Tools` is used.

What I have to select in `Command` in `External Tools` for Visual Studio 2013 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wanted to write for people who are searching the same subject : I don't get this error on Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate).

Comment: I think that this error is because of the lack of RAM.

Answer (score 18):

This happened to me.

For me, the reason was a bad IIS config file.

I was able to fix it by deleting the auto-generated IISExpress folder, which is usually located at `%userprofile%/Documents`, e.g. `C:\Users\[you]\Documents\IISExpress`.

When I ran the project again, it created a new folder with a valid IIS config file and I could run the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a new IISExpress folder is indeed created, it just did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me in a Web Site Project. The solution was to close the solution, delete the project's **.vs** folder and rebuild.

Comment: your answer is exactly what I needed. I had a copied project and this was showing error while running. Wonder why would anyone down-vote this comment.

Answer (score 3):

I had to move the solution folder to a new location. ie: from C:\Documents and Settings\David\Desktop\MySolution    to    C:\SourceCode\MySolution

I tried many of the other suggestions to no avail, but this worked a treat.

Answer (score 2):

you can change the default development server port no in Project(right click)-> Properties-> web->use visual studio web server-> use specific port-> and enter 1000 or any port no.

It will work !! Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be Skype using some ports which are configured in your project. Quit Skype and try again.

Also I noticed that if I delete the *%userprofile%/Documents/IISExpress* folder, then IISExpress will show a popup notification specifying exactly which program is blocking it from starting.

Answer (score 0):

while debugging the website an error was pooping `unable to connect configured development web server`

i have successfully resolve that error.

1) first uninstall the iis 8.0 from our system 
2) download iis 10.0 from `https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264` 
3) now open new project and check it out.

4) if still not working then check iis manager setting in that open default web site and open authentication and enable basic, form and windows authentication .

5) right click on default web site and select edit permission in that add full controll to iis user if it is not present please add it.

and check your project again. 
hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

unable to connect to configured web server

For me it worked out when i uninstalled skype and visual studio ,then deleted IIS folder from documents.....And again installed visual studio first then installed skype....Try it out...