# How does Visual Studio build applicationhost.config from a website?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I downloaded the files for a hosted kentico website and want to set them up to run locally.

When I open the project in VS2015 and build, an application.config file is generated in my user folder.

The binding protocol in this file is generated as

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:56956:localhost" />
```

which is not working.

Where does this binding information come from?

Comment: looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562040/unable-to-connect-the-configured-development-web-server-visual-studio-2013  I should change the default development server port. However I can not find this option in VS 2015 web site.