# unable to connect to the configured development web server in c# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, localhost

I have tried many solutions by google & stack as well but none of them is working for me. following error I am getting while running project in localhost. Other projects working fine only this have problem.

[image]

Seems to be it has problem with this port localhost://63477.

Comment: Try running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293572/how-to-solve-microsoft-visual-studio-vs-error-unable-to-connect-to-the-conf

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan as I said I have tried many solutions. And tried this as well but not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26509538/3664659

Answer (score 1):

Dear down voters I found the solution from own. I have created entire new project & copied old projects files in that & that worked for me.